# Getting objects like button from view. iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, view

I created a button in my cover.h file for my first view

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface cover : UIViewController 
{

     IBOutlet UIButton *Enter;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *Enter;
-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

and connected it with the actual button in the inteface builder by choosing File's Owner in the tiny box that gives you the choice of File's Owner, First Responder, and View

Then I went to cover.m file and added the following code

```
-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender
{

      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nextView" owner:self options:nil];
      NSLog(@"pressed");

}
```

SO when  I go to the nextView.xib and modify nextView.m and nextView.h and access its buttons and do the same thing I did for  cover.xib cover.m and cover.h , it doesn't work properly.

What happens is that when I click the enter button in the cover view it shuts down the app. This does not happen until I connected the button to function and outlet (Meaning when it was just switching views and the second view wasn't doing anything it would work)

Thank you for any help you can give. Sorry if I haven't given enough information, kinda new at this, but as find out more info I should have had, I will add it.

Thank you

Edit 1 :

I did not notice anywhere where it said there was an error or anything like that. It built correctly

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to connect the IBAction up to the button, drag a connection from the button to either File's Owner or First Responder (whatever is appropriate in your application) in interface builder

Comment: Just checked. I have connected the IBAction to the Button. When it is not connected the app runs and when I click enter it goes to the new view, but the button on the new view does not work. When I connect it, it does not go to the next view. It shuts down the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's convention to capitalize class names.  I'd Suggest `CoverViewController`.  This makes it more obvious, when reading your code, what we're looking at.

What is your intent here?  To show nib after nib of content?

Is the "files owner" of every nib a `CoverViewController`?

What you have actually done is (catastrophically) reloaded the views for the existing controller.  This will not end well.

What you want to do is create another instance of the same class:

```
-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender {
CoverViewController nextController = [[CoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nextView"];
[navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:NO];
}
```

If you're not using a nav controller, you probably want to be.
Read up on the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457).

Comment: It is essentially nib after nib of content, there are just nibs that need to be interactive. I have different controller for each nib, when in xcode, i created a UIViewController and checked the Xib for user interface box. The thing is I want to be able to naviagate with the buttons that are in the middle of the view. So I don't want to have have navigation  bar. Is there a way to hide the nav bar, and use buttons on the view in their place(or perhaps in conjunction with them)?

Comment: you want a navigation controller, you can hide the navigation bar - otherwise you'd have to change the root view controller each time (more of a pain) "You can hide and show the navigation bar using the navigationBarHidden property or setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method. " - [UINavigationController Class Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: But what about the buttons. I have a buttons that are gonna be used to transfer views. How would I use those buttons? Like the enter button I have shown in my code. (Sorry if I am being annoying/stupid)

Comment: you want to target the buttons as above (i edited the code to make it more obvious)